# Let $A$ be the collection of finite unions for $(a,b]\cap\mathbb{Q}$. Show that $A$ is an algebra. Problem 1.4.23(a), Folland's Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

For context, I am currently working through exercise 1.4.23(a) from Gerald Folland's *Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications* (2nd Edition). The question states the following:

> Let $A$ be the collection of finite unions of sets of the form $(a,b]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ where $-\infty\leq a<b\leq\infty$. (a.) Show that $A$ is an algebra on $\mathbb{Q}$. (Use Proposition 1.7.)

> **1.7 Proposition.** If $E$ is an elementary family, the collection $A$ of finite disjoint unions of members of $E$ is an algebra.

My concern comes from the following fact: all elementary families necessarily contain the empty set $\phi$. Knowing that $a<b$, we cannot say $\phi=(a,a]\cap\mathbb{Q}\in E$ given some $a\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$. Further, since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, it follows $\phi\neq(x-\delta,x+\delta]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R},\ \epsilon>0$; hence, $\phi\notin E$. Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 2):

There is an important distinction between the statement in your title and the statement you are supposed to prove.  Specifically,

Your title:

> Define $E$ to be the set of all intervals defined $(a,b]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$ and $a<b$. Show $\emptyset\in E$.

This is not valid.  With this definition, $\emptyset \not\in E$.

The question quoted in your body text:

> Let $A$ be the collection of finite unions of sets of the form $(a,b]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ where $-\infty\leq a<b\leq\infty$. (a.) Show that $A$ is an algebra on $\mathbb{Q}$. (Use Proposition 1.7.)

This is fine, because the empty union is a finite union.  Written another way, we know that (using the same $E$ from your title) $$A = \left\{\bigcup F : F \subset E \text{ and } F \text{ is finite}\right\}$$
Then $F = \emptyset \subset E$ is finite, so $\bigcup \emptyset = \emptyset \in A$.

Comment: I see. That makes a lot more sense, never thought of an empty union being a union. Thanks for the help, also good note for when asking questions going forward! I'm still new to the site, so I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: EDIT: fixed the title. Thanks again for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

First assume that you consider sets of the given form where $a=b$ is allowed. That is an elementary family Then the set of disjoint unions is an Algebra by the proposition. Call it $A_1$. Next prove that $A=A_1$ (when doing this, observe that in the definition of $A$ **not only finite disjoint unions are allowed, but all possible finite unions**). Since $A_1\subset A$ is obvious,  basically you need to prove that any set that is a finite union of subsets from the original $E$ can also be represented as a disjoint finite union of sets from the original $E$. You need to "disjointify" your union.

Comment: In other terms, to answer my initial question, should we assume that maybe it was a typo not to include the case where $a=b$? If so...I would like some justification unless what I have provided is enough?

Comment: No, it is not a typo.  Your original set $E$ is not an elementary family, but you are allowed to take non-disjoint unions, which compensates for not being such.

Comment: I edited my answer, I had mistaken the order of inclusions.

Comment: To answer your question about the empty set: observe that “finite unions” include union over an empty set of indices so the empty set belongs (trivially) to $A$.

Comment: Okay that makes more sense. Would you mind potentially notating what a union over an empty set of indices would look like? I'm having a hard time understanding how this would be a union: would not we need at least two sets given union is a binary operator? In which case, these two sets need satisfy the property given above?

Comment: Formally speaking, any set is the union with itself. When we say finite unions we mean unions $\cup_{I\in I}E_i$, where $I$ is any finite set of indices. In particular, you can have $I=\emptyset$ so your union does not contain any element.